# FullCalendar VueJS - Update date range

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I use the official [FullCalendar VueJS component](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue), and I would like to update the current range displayed in the view (**DayGridMonth** here) : 1 month, 2 months, 3 months, custom period

According to the "documentation", the `visibleRange` property can be updated thanks to the function `setOption()` (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange), but it doesn't work for me : the property is well updated in component, but the view wasn't updated.

I also tried to update state manually, without result.

This is my draft function to do this

```
    updateCurrentDate: function () {
        const calendarApi = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi();
        const date = new Date(calendarApi.getDate());
        let endRange;

        this.currentPeriodRange = calendarApi.state.dateProfile.activeRange;
        this.currentPeriodLabel = moment(date).format('MMMM YYYY');

        if (this.currentView === 'month') {
            endRange = moment(this.currentPeriodRange.start).add(2, 'month');
            this.currentPeriodRange.end = endRange.toDate();

          // Not working
          calendarApi.setOption('visibleRange', this.currentPeriodRange);

          // No one of these test work
          calendarApi.state.dateProfile.activeRange = this.currentPeriodRange; // 
          calendarApi.state.dateProfile.currentRange = this.currentPeriodRange;
          calendarApi.state.dateProfile.renderRange = this.currentPeriodRange;

        }

        if (this.currentPeriodRange.start !== this.currentPeriodRange.end) {
            this.currentPeriodLabel = this.currentPeriodLabel + ' - ' + endRange.format('MMMM YYYY');
        }

        return;
    },
```

Thanks for reading and answering

Comment: the visible range cannot be adjusted in a month view, it's a fixed grid always showing exactly one month. I doubt there's anything wrong with your code as such, you simply tried to make it do something that it doesn't do. Your code would be more likely to work if you specify a view like "timeGrid" or "list" or "timeline". It's unfortunate that the documentation doesn't mention this.

Comment: I'm very sad about your answer haha !
Don't you think I can surround this by the renderDates method which render each cells for this view ? By appending all missing cells manually in the DOM for exemple ?
I regret that the documentation for this VueJS component was so light...

Comment: It's not the vueJS documentation - that visibleRange method and documentation applies to all the flavours of fullCalendar, whether native JS, vueJS, Angular or whatever.

Comment: Anyway I think your suggested approach will not work - fullCalendar's internal rendering engine won't know about day/time slots you have added manually during callbacks, and will not know to place events there, even if those events match the created day. If you really wanted to enhance the "month" view, you'd have to do it by creating a [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) - probably by copying the month view code and then changing it. But that would be really quite a big job. And fullCalendar 5 is about to be released, so then you'd have to do it all again!

Comment: If I was you I would consider carefully how essential your requirement really is, before you go down this road. Maybe do some creative thinking and see if there is another satisfactory way of presenting the information, which makes use of existing features and options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advices. I will think about the custom view approach, and estimate that. If it's a too big job I will think about other solutions, for example, do this into list view only, for a better reading about the real purpose : events informations reading